# How can we modify network type within my app in android?

Tags: android, telecom-manager

I am really new to android app development . I am developing an app to a problem for and that is to SET Network type to LTE only .
I went to secret menu by using * # * # 4636 # *# * and change the settings to LTE only .
I just see logcat when I did it manually on phone and the log was something like this .

```
Telecom : PhoneAccountRegistrar: Modify account: [ComponentInfo{com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService}, ***, UserHandle{0}(cap: 1086 -> 1078)]: TSI.rPA@L74
```

Now I want to know how to do this within myapp .

First I tried to go into settings by this code but I don't know how to change it .

```
            Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            in.setClassName("com.android.settings" , "com.android.settings.RadioInfo");
            startActivity(in);
```

But don't know how to do changes in RadioInfo .

Comment: The phone would likely have to be [rooted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607263/android-4-0-4g-toggle) for doing it programmatically. Personally I'd prefer a short paragraph describing how to do it manually than allowing random app root access to my phone.

Comment: Yeah you right rooting phone is not a good idea . I'll do it manually after it .Thanks @Martheen .